# What is the correct way to access an instance variable in a model method from another controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created some scaffolding to manage audio clips which are going to be organized by index:

```
rails generate scaffold Clips name:string
```

I uploaded all the clips to my file server, and added them to the db using the auto generated rails control panel.

Now, I need to be able to access them, so I added a url method to the model:

```
class Clip < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.url
        "http://example.file_server.com/audio-clips/#{@id}.mp3"
    end
end
```

Now, in the controller than runs the site itself, calling this method looks like it outputs everything but the id....

```
class TwilioController < ApplicationController
    def index

        Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
            @response = r.play Clip.where(name: "root").url
        end

        render :xml => @response
    end
end
```

Outputs:

```
<Response>
<play>http://example.file_server.com/audio-clips/.mp3</play>
</Response>
```

How can I get this thing to insert the `id` into the URL string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things, one, you defined `url` as `self.url`, which makes it a class level method.  I'm guessing you didn't want to do that.

Also, don't use `id` as an instance variable, use its generated accessor method:

```
class Clip < ActiveRecord::Base
  def url
    "http://example.file_server.com/audio-clips/#{id}.mp3"
  end
end
```

Also, you are calling `url` right after the `where` call, which returns a relation.  You'll want to do something like:

```
Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
  @response = r.play Clip.where(name: "root").first.url
end
```

But that depends more on what you are doing.  If you expect there to be several results, you'll have to handle it differently.  Also beware it may return no results...

Comment: I ended up doing `self` because of the relation problem. adding `.first` fixed my issue. Thanks!